# list methods with same name in a Python package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a Python package in which I have different `Classes` with a common method called `map`. That method always returns a function and is intended to be use inside a method of another package. Is there a way to lists all methods that are called `map` inside my package?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to dip into a bit of reflection on this one. The steps you need are to load a reference a given module, grab the list of classes and then examine each class to make sure it has the method `map`:

```
import sys, inspect

def map_classes(module_name):
  for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[module_name]):
    if inspect.isclass(obj):
      try:
        if callable(getattr(obj, 'map')):
          yield name
      except AttributeError:
        pass
```

This method will return a generator of all names of all classes within a module that have a `map` method. Note, if they have a `map` attribute, it will not return the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `inspect` package.  Everything you need is built-in.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> for name, obj in np.__dict__.items():
...   if hasattr(obj,"tolist"):
...     print name, obj
```

Comment: This will not work with inherited methods. Plain `hasattr` / `getattr` with a fixed name would, though.

Comment: `inspect` is built-in; `numpy` is not.

Comment: @zondo ??  This is just inspecting `numpy` as an example.  `numpy` is not an integral part of the process here.

Comment: @9000 I'm not sure what you mean.
    >>> class A:
    ...   def blah(self):
    ...     return 5
    ... 
    >>> class B(A):
    ...   pass
    ... 
    >>> hasattr(B,"blah")

Comment: @Scott: Indeed, `hasattr` does work! `.__dict__.items()`, as seen in the answer, does not. That is, `__dict__` won't include inherited attribute names, while `hasattr` does the necessary MRO lookup.

Comment: Can modules inherit attributes?

Comment: Module's dict would reveal all, and modules don't do inheritance; the original question is about _classes,_ hence my notice about inherited _methods_.

Comment: the `for` loop over `__dict__.items()` is for his requirement "in my package".  Loop over everything in the package, then use `hasattr` to see if the thing has an attribute "map".  Doesn't involve taking the `__dict__` of a class.  I see what you're saying now though.